# Error building the project in android studio - Could not download aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows.jar

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

im building a project with react-native and using android studio, suddenly this error appeared:

```
Could not download aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.3-5435860): No cached version available for offline mode
```

to be honest, I dont know anything about android studio, I just run the emulator and thats it, so I really dont know what could be the problem, here Im going to show a capture:

[image]

how can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncheck offline work in settings.

Go to File -> Settings.
And open the 'Build,Execution,Deployment'.
Build Tools -> Gradle - > uncheck -> Offline work

Comment: im in Build, Execution, Deployment, but theres no Build Tools -> Gradle - > uncheck -> Offline work

Comment: Try searching offline in settings search bar.

Comment: solve it, just need to go to gradle and uncheck the offline work as you said, but the location of gradle is different for each android studio version, in my case 4.0.1, its located in View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle, thanks